# GetStream Laravel - Quick remove user's timeline

Tags: laravel-5.4, getstream-io

I need to have the ability on my app to "remove" a user's account.  Basically, remove his posts, likes, articles etc. etc.,  What is the correct way of handling this in GetStream?  Is there a feature so all his activities will no longer be seen by everyone following him? or what approach is best for this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to remove all the activities for that user. If it takes a while to do this: consider doing it in a background job. If you need them removed instantly, you can add an extra filter layer in your application, that check every activity you get from Stream, to checks if the actor of an activity is removed or not.

I hope this helps!

Cheers